# A few basic django questions

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions

I am a newbie in django, and I need some examples on this code I am working on.

I have a textbox, and an output on the same template and this is the view for this:

```
def sessiontest(request):
    a=request.session.get('a',{})
    form=sform()
    return render_to_response('cart.html',{'form':form,'a':a},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the view for processing the data is this :

```
def sessiontest2(request):
 if request.method=="POST":
     form=sform(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         request.session['a']=form.cleaned_data["name"]
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(sessiontest))
```

It is working fine if i just need to store ONE value, but how do I allow my request.session['a'] to store multiple data everytime there is a new input such as  `{value1,value2,new_value,new_value}` ? I need it to be in a format which I can display with a `{% for i in a %}` loop in my templates and be used to filter my models.

This is just a test code, later on I will need to store my product_id in it and use it to filter my items in this way:

```
items=models.products.objects.filter(pk=request.session["a"])
```

Please give me some hints on how this could be done.

Comment: Start here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `{% for i in a %}` IF you are passing a list in the template from the views. Like the query `items=models.products.objects.filter(pk=request.session["a"])` will provide a list of the object over which you can iterate and display attributes.
You can use a dictionary for this if you want to store multiple items. `request.session['a']['value1'] = 'value1'`

You can access the dictionary in templates by using

```
{% for key, val in dict.items %}
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    <td>{{ val }}</td>
{%  endfor  %}
```

OR you can use for loop counter to differentiate between values while stroing like this

```
count=0 

for i in val: 
  count+=1   
  request.session[a+str(count)]=i
```

Then you can access it like `request.session["a1"]` and so on for other values 
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The best possible  way is to create another model  which will store the session id for that session and the model will have a manytomany relationships with your product object .

Models.py

class Storedsessionproducts(models.Model):
        products=models.ManytoManyField(Products,null=True,related-name="storedproducts")

Now in your view.py set your session id to the created Storedsessionproducts of that session 
    # use session_id to retrieve the current Storedsessionproducts object 
    and then pull out all products from it 
    session_id=request.session.get('cart_id')

```
## assuming you have successfully created Storedsessionproducts
# add all created products in Storedsessionproducts
request.session['cart_id']=Storedsessionproducts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to store the data as a list of values. An easy way to do this is:

```
request.session.setdefault('a', []).append(form.cleaned_data['name'])
```

This sets an empty list as the default if the key `'a'` does not exist in the session, and then appends the name to the new or existing list. You can query for these objects using the following query:

```
Products.objects.filter(id__in=request.session.get('a', []))
```